# Password encryption in Auth0

Tags: auth0

I am using the free version of Auth0. I've two questions

1. What encryption does Auth0 use to encrypt a password?
2. Can I use custom encryption to store password?

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 never store passwords in cleartext. Passwords are always hashed and salted using bcrypt. Additionally, data encryption is offered at rest and in transit by using TLS with at least 128-bit AES encryption.